# Vue instantsearch: save and restore state programmatically

Tags: algolia, vue-instant-search

I have a use case where I need to save current search state, e.g. query, selected facets etc., and restore them on demand without using the history. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

It’s a bit advanced but you can use [getState()](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/reference.html#AlgoliaSearchHelper#getState) using the `algoliasearchHelper`:

```
var client = algoliasearch('appid', 'appsearch');
var helper = algoliasearchHelper(client, 'index', {
  facets: ['shipping'],
  disjunctiveFacets: ['category']
});

var mySavedState = helper.getState();
```

Or a part of the state with all the refinements on attributes and the query:

```
var mySavedState = helper.getState(['query', 'attribute:category']);
```

It returns an object, so you could use `JSON.stringify(mySavedState)` to save it somewhere, then `JSON.parse(mySavedState)` to get it back.

Then later you can set the state:

```
helper.setState(mySavedState);
```

For more, see [Getting started with the helper](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/gettingstarted.html).